# JumpList won't work using QWinJumpList

Tags: c++, qt, windows-8.1, jump-list

I have following code in `main.cpp`:

```cpp
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QWinJumpListItem wjli(QWinJumpListItem::Link);
wjli1.setArguments(QStringList(QString("as")));
wjli1.setDescription("Some Text");
wjli1.setTitle("Some Text");
QWinJumpList wjl;
wjl.tasks()->setTitle("Some Title");
wjl.tasks()->addItem(&wjli1);
wjl.tasks()->setVisible(true);
```

This one should (in my opinion) add a link to the Win8 Jumplist, but, althoug aplication compiles without errors, the link `Some Text` does not show up in the JumpList. Is there any member of `QWinJumpList` that should be called to initiate the JumpList? What should be done to make that working? I couldn't find anything like that in doc.

I'm using QTCreator with Qt5.3 installed on 64-bit Win8.1 Update 1. Compilator: MinGW

Comment: I can't get it to work either. However, I got the suspicion that the problem is related to the `tasks()` category. Because the `recent()` category seems to work fine (see the musicplayer example).
Despite that: i think you forgot to set the filePath (`setFilePath()`) of the QWinJumpListItem!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in Qt WinExtras. It doesn't even work in their manual test "jumplist" (which can be found in the source code tree at `Src/qtwinextras/tests/manual/jumplist`).

I filed an issue in their bug tracker: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41155

Comment: Update: The fix is scheduled for Qt 5.4